# jQuery 1.0.1 vs 1.1.0 RC Radio buttons bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I got some radio controls that in JQuery Mobile 1.0.1 (stable) were working pretty good, but when I test the new RC (1.1.0), I can't get those work.

Here's how I defined the radio group

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Mostra elementi gi&agrave; letti</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radioMostraElementiLettiSi" value="si"/>
                <label for="radioMostraElementiLettiSi">Si</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-view" id="radioMostraElementiLettiNo" value="no"/>
                <label for="radioMostraElementiLettiNo">No</label>
            </fieldset>
```

And here's the code I use to check it

```
if($('#radioMostraElementiLettiSi').attr("checked"))
        var showReadElements = "si";
    else
        var showReadElements = "no";
```

The problem is that in stable version, when the radio I listen to is checked, it correctly enters in the IF condition, in the new version it's always undefined.

Moreover, when I try and listen for the change event to fire... it just never fire, while in version 1.0.1 it triggers correctly...

Here's the code I use for the change event

```
$('#radioMostraElementiLettiSi').live('change',function(){

alert("Trigger!");
});
```

Is it me doing something wrong or they just changed something?

Comment: This was a bug and is now fixed: - https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3687#issuecomment-4251371

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500742/get-checked-radio-button-when-migrate-to-jqm-1-1-rc1-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was fixed, use latest version until new RC version released.
http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/04/16/latest/